# Magento order page is not rendered correctly

Tags: php, magento

I have a Magento store which was working working fine but the client has installed something and the order page is disturbed. I have turned off all the extra extensions but cannot find the problem.

I am attaching the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Maybe admin CSS is being overwritten by extension?

Comment: Yes the prototype JavaScript have some problems. But I am not sure how to fix it.